# How to rewrite rule for all https trafic using htacces except one subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am using this `htaccess` code for redirect all `http` to `https`:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It works for:

```
www.example.com
www.domain1.example.com
www.nohttps.example.com
```

So, I don't want to use this rule for `www.nohttps.example.com` how can I do this? I dont know.

thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a condition to exclude a subdomain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?nohttps\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?nohttps\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to use a new browser to test this change.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, yes, it working, but.. i want to redirecet 'nohttps' always to http. When I put https://nohttps.com I want redirect to http://nohttps.com .